# PCA inputs error Argument with more than 65535

Tags: apache-spark, pca, apache-spark-mllib

When using PCA in spark.mllib.feature, the cols of my input data is over 65535, but the RowMatrix defined in PCA is <65535, does it means I can't use PCA?

Comment: @eliasah,the error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument with more than 65535 cols: 84619  at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.checkNumColumns(RowMatrix.scala:135)

Comment: if the one of the answers provided solves your problems, please accept it so we can close this question !

Answer (score 6):

Currently the PCA implementation seems to have a limitation of fitting d^2 covariance/grammian matrix entries in memory (d is the number of columns/dimensions of the matrix).

It's fixed to 65535 for now, because the current implementation of PCA isn't much scalable. So you can't actually use PCA in your case.

Reference: [source code.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L130)

There were a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7856) planning to implement a probabilistic principal component analysis algorithm which should be scalable but it seems like it's been resolved as **Won't Fix**.

Comment: @LiYu Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks.